# Why not use the engine of a model aircraft for other purpose?

Tags: piston-engine

I was reading the [DLE-120 engine User Manual](https://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/673073/dle-120.html?page=4) and saw this sentence:

- **This engine was designed for use in a model aircraft. Do not attempt to use it for any other purpose.**

Why? Why not use the engine of a model aircraft for other purpose? What does mean "model aircraft"? Does this mean only RC aircraft or RC and UAVs?

Is there any technical or safety reasons why this engine could not be used in a different application, not involving a model aircraft?

Comment: FWIW, there is no regulatory teeth to this disclaimer in case you were pondering that issue.  If you bought it you now own it; use it to power your blow dryer, blender, or whatever you like.

Comment: But opinion or tribal knowledge based answers are always being dumped on, ergo, they go in comments.

Comment: Somewhere out there is a Homer-Simpson-a-like who can proudly say, "They have to say that because of me"

Comment: A possible technical reason might be that it needs the airflow for proper cooling.

Comment: @jamesqf Perfect comment!

Comment: You don't need to mount an engine in something other than a specific type of aircraft to give it proper airflow. And if that were the case the instructions would say that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lawyer wrote that. It means if you use it for any other purpose, they are not liable and you are.

Comment: I suggest you to add @jamesqf 's comment to your answer.

Comment: No. That makes no sense.